# Consume XML data from 2 files and combine results in dynamically generated line items

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am using jQuery to consume XML data from 2 separate XML files and use that data to build line items in an unordered list on a page in a single-page PhoneGap app. Each XML file contains part of the line item - descriptive text and href for a mp4 file. My code seems to work, but the page creation works randomly, sometimes showing the results, line items with no text, or no results. Based on what I have read, I think this is due to the asynchronous nature of Ajax. I think I am using the pagebeforecreate from jQuery Mobile correctly, but this might be an issue too. Can someone please provide a recommendation or explain my results?

```
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#pageCE', function(event) {
    getXMLData("GetVideo", 3, "CE");
    getXMLData("GetDesc", 3, "CE");
  });

  function getXMLData(elementName, categoryId, eventType) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "somewebsitename.com/..." + elementName + categoryId,
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
      success: function(xmlData) {
          parseXml(xmlData, elementName, eventType);
      }
    });
  }

  function parseXml(xmlData, elementName, eventType) {
    var i = 0;
    var targetOutputList = "#outputList" + eventType;
    if (elementName === "GetVideo") {
      $(xmlData).find('string').each(function() {
         $(targetOutputList).append('<li><a href="' + $(this).text() + '"><p id="outputLineItem' + i + '"></p></a></li>');
         i++;
      });
    }
    else if (elementName === "GetDesc") {
      var targetElement = "#outputLineItem" + i;
      $(xmlData).find('string').each(function() {
        $(targetElement).append($(this).text());
        i++;
        targetElement = "#outputLineItem" + i;
      });
    }   
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Does getXMLData("GetVideo", 3, "CE"); need to complete before getXMLData("GetDesc", 3, "CE"); is started? If so, I would put the second ajax call within the success function. Even if the ajax is synchronous, the callback functions like success may not be.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your question. Yes, GetVideo needed to be completed before GetDesc. I was building a line item by creating the line item with the results of GetVideo and adding the GetDesc. I tried adding the callback in the success function, but could no t get it to work. I found  $.when and .done in jQuery and that seems to work. I even had to add a third ajax request to get image names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with jquery-mobile, but it looks like your problem is being caused by calling the function that processes the data from both ajax calls as soon as the first one returns. If the `GetDesc` request is the first one to return then there is no target element for it to append. Your `parseXml()` function is also setting `i` back to 0 every time it is called, so that's got to be causing some problems.

I would suggest writing an interim function that saves the xmlData to a variable, checks if the other xmlData has returned and only call the parsing function if it has.

```
var getVideo = null;
var getDesc = null;

function checkData(xmlData, elementName, eventType)
{
    if(elementName === "GetVideo")
    {
        getVideo = new Object();
        getVideo.xmlData = xmlData;
        getVideo.elementName = elementName;
        getVideo.eventType = eventType;

        if(getDesc != null)
        {
            parseXml();
        }
    }
    else if(elementName === "GetDesc")
    {
        getDesc = new Object();
        getDesc.xmlData = xmlData;
        getDesc.elementName = elementName;
        getDesc.eventType = eventType;

        if(getVideo != null)
        {
            parseXml();
        }
    }
}
```

If you call this function on success of your ajax call, you will have all of your data before you start parsing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did some more searching and found the answer using the $.when and .done in jQuery. This allows also asynchronous activities to finish and then process the tasks in the done. I need to get a book to better understand the jQuery fundamentals. Got any recommendations?

Comment: @chow -You might want to look at the tutorials on the jquery website: [http://learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com)